# Make circles around arrows in a Quiver plot. Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I have a dataset with 4 variables of a moving point; "x", "y", start point, "x1", "y1", endpoints. I have to make a quiver plot and then add circles around arrows. I tried using plt.Circle but it gave me an error. my end goal is to make 4(3 or 5 is fine too as long as all have equal) circles around each arrow with the largest being the point that has moved the furthest,i.e; biggest arrow. I am attaching a sample DataFrame, my code, the error I got when I attempted to make the first circle and desired output.

```py
df=pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,3], 'y':[2,4,6], 'x1':[2,4,6],'y1':[4,6,10]})

ax = plt.quiver(df['x'],df['y'],df['x1'],df['y1'])
circle2 = plt.Circle((5, 5), 0.5, color='b', fill=False)
ax.add_artist(circle2)
plt.xlim(0,7)
plt.ylim(0,11)
plt.show()
```

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-a817aecb842e> in <module>
      3 ax = plt.quiver(df['x'],df['y'],df['x1'],df['y1'])
      4 circle2 = plt.Circle((5, 5), 0.5, color='b', fill=False)
----> 5 ax.add_artist(circle2)
      6 plt.show()

AttributeError: 'Quiver' object has no attribute 'add_artist'
```

my current output:
[image: Current output]

and my desired output. If someone can help me, it will be great.
[image: Desired output]

Comment: Probably better to do `fig, ax = plt.subplots()` at the beginning and then directly `ax.quiver...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`quiver` return as `Quiver` object, in order to get the corresponding `AxesSubplot` object you need the `axes` property:

```
ax.axes.add_artist(circle2)
```

Full example:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,3], 'y':[2,4,6], 'x1':[2,4,6],'y1':[4,6,10]})
scale = 10
ax = plt.quiver(df['x'],df['y'],df['x1'],df['y1'], angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=scale)

n_circles = 4
rmax = np.sqrt(df.x1**2+df.y1**2).max() / scale
for i in range(1,1+n_circles):
    r = rmax * i / n_circles
    for circle in [plt.Circle((x,y), r, color='b', fill=False) for x,y in zip(df.x, df.y)]:
        ax.axes.add_artist(circle)

plt.xlim(0,8)
plt.ylim(0,8)
ax.axes.get_figure().set_size_inches(3,3)
```

[image]